# Firefox Does not read keyboard on google drive sites

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard, firefox, input, google-drive

Sites like google docs, sheets, slides, drive do not read the keyboard input but the keyboard works on other sites.  All google apps work in Chromium.

Linux Mint 21.1